# counting employees supervised by a manager

Tags: sql, oracle, directed-acyclic-graphs

Assume I have a table called 'Hierarchy' with two columns: 'manager' and 'subordinate'

Each entry in this table shows a relation between a manager and the employee they manage. e.g:

```
manager              subordinate

CEO                  regional_director
CEO                  store_manager
regional_director    store_manager
store_manager        cashier
```

My question is how can I obtain the number of subordinates for each manager, whether

**explicitly defined** e.g. CEO is manager of regional_director as (CEO --> regional director)

OR

**implicitly defined** e.g. regional_director is manager of cashier as

(regional_director --> store_manager --> cashier).

The problem with the data entries in the table is that, whilst implicit relations between a manager and their subordinate's subordinate **should** count towards the number of employees that person manages, there may also be an entry in the table with an explicit relation between the two and should not be counted twice. e.g.

```
CEO --> regional_director

regional_director --> store_manager

**BUT ALSO**

CEO --> store_manager
```

---

**ON THE OTHER HAND**

---

```
regional_director --> store_manager

store_manager --> cashier

**but there does NOT exist a relation:**

regional_director --> cashier
```

As this query will be run in JDBC, the output can be manipulated with java to obtain the desired results, however I would prefer to use mostly sql.

The output for for this example would be as follows:

```
Employee             num_subordinates

CEO                  3
regional_director    2
store_manager        1
```

Whilst thinking of a solution I realized my problem could be modeled by a directed acyclic graph like the one below:

[image]

Where the vertices are employees and the directed edges meaning 'manager of'.

In terms of the graph, I believe my question would translate to: For each vertex v, how many other vertices are reachable with a path of any length starting from vertex v.

vertex 7 would be able to reach vertices 8,9,11,2,10 so it's value would be 5

Sorry for such a long question.

Comment: Step 1) write some code  Step 2) Optionally ask questions if you have any problems

Comment: That is the problem I am having, I have no idea where to start. Do you think I would spend this much time structuring a question if I wasn't completely stuck?

Comment: Don't try to solve the whole thing at once; design it. Surely, you know *somewhere* you could start.

Comment: I have spent an age going through possible solutions which is where I got the idea of using acyclic directed graphs from but I was looking for a more sql based aproach. I'm not asking for an answer, just to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Are those numbers correct? You say regional director has 2 but is only listed in the table once and regional_director --> cashier doesn't exist.

Comment: regional_director cashier doesn't exist but is implicitly accounted for by regional_director --> store_manager --> cashier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple version would be:

```
with tree (manager, subordinate) as (
select manager ,subordinate from hierarchy 
union all 
select t.manager, h.subordinate  from tree t
   join hierarchy h
   on t.subordinate = h.manager 
   ) select manager, count(distinct subordinate ) 
     from tree
     group by manager
```

It may be improved by removing already existing nodes on next loops. But it may be achieved  also by simple distinct that is used in **count**.

Here is sample : [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b3c/1/0)

It may be improved also with endless loop protection.

```
with tree (manager, subordinate, path) as (
select manager ,subordinate, manager || '->' || subordinate from hierarchy 
union all 
select t.manager, h.subordinate, t.path || '->' || h.subordinate from tree t
   join hierarchy h
   on t.subordinate = h.manager   
   where instr(path, h.subordinate) = 0
     ) select manager , count(distinct subordinate)
     from tree
     group by manager
```

We use here **path** that shows us jumps between nodes. If **subordinate** is already on the path then skip it.

Sample is here :[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b3c/2/0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the first time i've encountered trees in sql but this definitely seems like the right approach. As I understand it, since you are using calls to the tree's contents within the creation of the tree, this leads to a sort of recursion like this: http://justpaste.it/pk5y . Also, if I understand correctly, the improved version would provide protection from cases such as: CEO-->regional_director-->store_manager-->CEO. Please correct me if I have misunderstood anything.

Comment: @Shiftz Basically you are right. You can play with it to see the real results by introducing additional **level** value. Add **level** after path in first line.  After that in the first select set 0 as level and on the second select set **t.level + 1**.  Don't group and just show results by `select * from tree`

Answer (score 1):

One way to get quite close, using standard SQL, is to use a set of statements catering for each level (direct, indirect-level-1, indirect-level-2), and excluding those that have already been counted. [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ad62/1) for the direct and 1st level case:

```
-- count direct reports
-- count indirect-at-one-level-of-separation reports
--   excluding counted-elsewhere (direct) reports
select 1, manager, count(*)
from hierarchy
group by manager
union
select 2, h1.manager, count(*)
from hierarchy h1, hierarchy h2
where h1.subordinate=h2.manager
  and not exists (
    select i1.manager
    from hierarchy i1
    where i1.manager=h1.manager
      and i1.subordinate=h2.subordinate
    )
group by h1.manager
order by 2, 1
```

You'll need to add up the entries. But this is going to get really messy as the levels increase. Oracle's `connect by` might help - I haven't tried it.

I'm guessing this is a case to do the work in Java, perhaps using a set?